# SQAlchemy limit relationship() to one record in time series

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have the following SQLAlchemy definitions:

```
class ThingValue(Base):

  __tablename__ = "ThingValues"

  thing_id = Column("ThingID", Integer, ForeignKey("Things.ThingID"), primary_key=True)
  date = Column("Date", Date, primary_key=True)
  value = Column("Value", Float, nullable=False)

class Thing(Base):

  __tablename__ = "Things"

  thing_id = Column("ThingID", Integer, primary_key=True)

  thing_value_at_start = relationship(ThingValue, primaryjoin=(ThingValue.thing_id==thing_id, ThingValue.date.month == 1, ThingValue.date.year == 2021), uselist=False)
```

I'm trying to define the property `thing_value_at_start` to be the single record in `ThingValues` that has a date in January, 2021.  I cannot come up with anything form of the `relationship` command that does not throw an error.

I do not want to pull in the entire relationship set of `ThingValues` for each `Thing` and then filter later as that is not sufficiently performant in this case.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Below should do it:

```
thing_value_at_start = relationship(
    ThingValue,
    primaryjoin=and_(
        ThingValue.thing_id == thing_id,
        extract('month', ThingValue.date) == 1,
        extract('year', ThingValue.date) == 2021,
    ),
    uselist=False,
)
```

1. You need SQL expressions for the JOIN, and therefore using python expressions does not do the job. `extract` should work on all supported RDBMS
2. you do need `and_`.